# i wanted to get the input from user and pass the value to (average=dict[x]/6) and there by getting the result

Tags: python

Below is a program which i am trying for studying purpose.

```
print("Students_performance_Application") 
x = raw_input("Enter your name : ") 
dict{"Rajesh":"456","Ranjith":"500","Ram":"456"}
average=dict[x]/6
print("Your average is {}%".format(Average))
if Average > 90:
    print(" Hello patron , your Grade is S ")
elif((Average < 90) and (Average >= 60)):
    print(" Hello patron , your Grade is B ")
elif((Average < 60) and (Average > 40)):
    print(" Hello patron , your Grade is C ")
else:
    print(" Hello patron , you have to redo the exams ")
```

As you can see i wanted to get the input from user and pass the value to (average=dict[x]/6) and there by getting the result. 
but even if i pass "Rajesh" or "Ranjith" as input value.

I am getting below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\results.py", line 5, in <module>
    average=dict[x]/6
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: This is my program : Program::`print("Students_performance_Application")
x=raw_input("Enter your name : ")
dict={"Rajesh":"456","Ranjith":"500","Ram":"456"}
average=dict[x]/6
print("Your average is {}%".format(Average))
if Average > 90:
    print(" Hello patron , your Grade is S ")
elif((Average < 90) and (Average >= 60)):
    print(" Hello patron , your Grade is B ")
elif((Average < 60) and (Average > 40)):
    print(" Hello patron , your Grade is C ")
else:
    print(" Hello patron , you have to redo the exams ")`

Comment: Please post your code in the question not in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the score in the dictionary to **int object**. You are getting the error because you are trying to divide a string object with integer(`average=dict[x]/6`).

```
print("Students_performance_Application") 
x=raw_input("Enter your name : ") 
dict={"Rajesh":456,"Ranjith":500,"Ram":456}    #---->Update
average=dict[x]/6 
print("Your average is {}%".format(average)) 
if average > 90: 
    print(" Hello patron , your Grade is S ") 
elif((average < 90) and (average >= 60)): 
    print(" Hello patron , your Grade is B ") 
elif((average < 60) and (average > 40)): 
    print(" Hello patron , your Grade is C ") 
else: 
    print(" Hello patron , you have to redo the exams ")
```